# apache2 reverse proxy 404 error

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have set up an apache2 server. I am trying to enable a site to reverse proxy in which I will redirect /registry to :5000.

I have apache2 up and running and am able to reach the default page () but am having trouble getting my reverse proxy to work. I have created a file as such:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#
ServerName http://myhost.org
#
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-docker.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-docker.log combined
    ProxyPass /registry myhost.org:5000
    ProxyPassReverse /registry myhost.org:5000
#
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to the url `myhost.org/registry` I get the following:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /registry was not found on this server.
```

I know the site is enabled because I have checked this:

```
sudo a2ensite proxiedhosts
Site proxiedhosts already enabled
```

Any help with the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Figured it out. I had the path set wrong (/var/www) was incorrect. I just removed that line and it works.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry. I figured this out. Looks like the problem was my path in /var/www/ was incorrect.

It was essentially referencing a path that did not exist.